# Python eyed3 and getting Musicbrainz tags

Tags: python, mp3, id3, eyed3

Hello is it possible to read Musicbrainz tags with eyed3 in python?

I can do the following...

```
audiofile = eyed3.load(sys.argv[1])
artist = audiofile.tag.artist
album = audiofile.tag.album
...
```

But I cant find the Musicbrainz tags...

```
mbid = audiofile.tag.MUSICBRAINZ_ALBUMID
```

I couldn't find any info on how to list all tags, so I used another piece of software to find the tag names.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure *eyeD3* recognizes one of the [ID3v2](https://id3.org/Developer%20Information#The_ID3v2_documents) tags.
2. List all `UFID` or `TXXX` frames (or for ID3v2.2 `TXX`). Since they're general purpose containers you have to further investigate them.
3. In your case search for [the latter with a description](https://picard-docs.musicbrainz.org/v2.4/en/appendices/tag_mapping.html#id23) of `MusicBrainz Album Id`.

You "cant find the Musicbrainz tags" because they don't exist as such. It's like living with your parents is possible without having/needing your own bell at the door. *eyeD3* also doesn't seem to support any of the other metadata formats where *MusicBrainz* details may reside - in general you can expect *ID3* to appear in MP3 files, so it should work for you in most if not all cases.